# Why there is no much change in the incremental backup size of level 0 and level 1

Tags: backup, oracle-11g-r2, rman

I'm implementing incremental backup in my database. As per my knowledge after level 0 backup, level 1 backup will take only the backups of changes that are done. But in my db after level 0 full backup, level 1 backup is also taking the almost same backup size of level 0.

On Friday, level 0 backup. **Backup Size: 49.8 GB**

BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;

On Saturday, level 1 backup. **Backup Size: 45.2 GB**

BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;

Is there any mistake which I have done here in the RMAN command. Please help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in my db after level 0 full backup, level 1 backup is also taking
>   the almost same backup size of level 0.

Verify if the backup generated in level 0 exists there in the location, while level 1 backup occurs.

The level 0 backup might have got deleted or removed from the location. This might be the reason for this issue.

Comment: Thankyou... Level 0 backup got deleted from FRA before level 1 was taken. That's why I was facing this issue.